# Hide a column with buttons in cxGrid

Tags: button, hide, tcxgrid

I have a cxGrid with a columne that holds some buttons and I would like to be able to hide this column
The reason for this is that I use the same grid for printing that I use for input. But there are some columns that isn't wanted on the report.
I know how to hide a column by using GetColumnByFieldName but I can't figure out how to do it with the button column since it has no fieldname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem for now by setting a fieldname for the column and then use GetColumnByFieldName to get access to its Visible property.

It might not be the best solution, but for now it is OK